# Why does the down-vote popup say: "This question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear,or not useful."?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I've notices that when the pointer hovers over the down-vote button there is a popup that says: "This question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear,or not useful."  Is that what down-voting a post is meant to indicate?  Just curious.

Comment: Yes, that is what it is supposed to indicate.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Note that, on this meta site, the way I've noticed it apparently being used, the way I sometimes use it myself, and I've seen several statements about it, is that a down-vote instead generally just means disagreement with what the post is saying. Conversely, an up-vote often means general agreement with the post.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I was actually asking in regards to math.se since there seems to be some confusion among participants as to what the intent of the down-vote feature is.

Comment: This wording is standard on many SE sites, and is necessarily a terse summary of what makes a Question "bad" (note that it simply negates the hover wording for upvote buttons).  A more detailed set of guidelines is shown at [ask].  What users consider useful (or adequate researching) is an opinion, but this is consistent with the theory of Community Moderation.

Answer (score 4):

This question comes up on many of the StackExchange sites; see for example [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5755?rq=1) for example, which in turns references another site.  The wording is fixed across sites, and is intended to provide a helpful reminder to someone thinking about up- or down-voting.

There has also been discussion in the past about changing the tooltip, particularly for Meta sites where up- and down-voting often carries a connotation of agreeing or disagreeing with a proposal; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93759/wording-of-upvote-downvote-tooltips-and-faq-on-meta-sites) for example (that's a duplicate but I think has more useful discussion than the main question it links to).

So directly answering: an upvote on the main site should indicate that the question has made some *effort* (not necessarily research, depending on the site), or has value in some clearly definable way.  A downvote, contrariwise, indicates that insufficient effort has been made in producing the question.  On Meta, votes may in fact be indicating approval or disapproval instead, especially if the *feature-request* tag is present.

Comment: I got in trouble for downvoting questions by one person that could be sieved the same, and because output from code that had errors. I consider it crank behaviour, and the code I found out wasn't even written by them ( not to mention it got a debate going after I pointed out the wrong output).